# How to use tensorflow-gpu in unity mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, ml-agent, tensorflowsharp

I'm prototyping mobile ml application within Unity engine.
I have trained tensorflow graph (.pb) and I want to run the model in unity mobile. (both android and ios)
With [OpenCVForUnity](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/opencv-for-unity-21088) plugin, with dnn module, I can run tensorflow graph in mobile. But the problem is that's running on CPU.

I need GPU based solution and it seems that OpenCVForUnity isn't proper approach for that.
So any idea for running graph on GPU in unity mobile enviroment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [Barracuda](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.barracuda@0.3/manual/index.html), which will allow you to convert a tensorflow model and use it in cross-platform Unity applications. [Unity ML-Agents](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/) uses Barracuda, so you could use their code as a reference for how to utilize your neural network.